# Upgrade TYPO3 version 9 to TYPO3 LTS with symlink

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have tried to upgrade TYPO3 version 9.0.0 to the LTS version. I have followed the below steps.

**TYPO3 version 9.0.0 to TYPO3 LTS**

1) Enable symlink typo3_src folder to

```
ln -s typo3 typo3_src
```

This showing upgrade button enabled to perform the upgrade.

[image]

2) After that, I performed an upgrade process.

Nothing happens when I click the button, this only showing a message like this.

[image]

**TYPO3 version 9.5.6 to TYPO3 LTS**

I have performed the same steps to check the functionality in the TYPO3 version 9.5.6

This download the latest version of the typo3 in the root directory

[image]

in the root and shows success message

[image]

As per showing in the message, Its tell me to reload browser because the system has been upgraded. But, after reloading it not showing the latest version of the TYPO3.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your symlink isn't set correct.

you wrote:
    `ln -s typo3 typo3_src`

what links in the false direction.

The correct symlinks for TYPO3 (9.5.8) are:

```
ln -s typo3_src-9.5.8/ typo3_src
ln -s typo3_src/typo3 typo3
ln -s typo3_src/index.php
```

The `ln -s` commands syntax is:
`ln -s <source> <targetname>`

Comment: Can you please give If you have document link if available? Or steps for upgrading TYPO3 9.5.6 to LTS?

Comment: here is the link where the symlinks are described:  
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/singlehtml/#installing-on-a-unix-server

Comment: No need to repeat the folder `ln -s typo3_src/typo3 typo3` you can just type `ln -s typo3_src/typo3`

Answer (score 1):

I think your folder structure is incorrect. The correct structure would be:

typo3_src -> /path/to/typo3_src-9.5.x

typo3 -> typo3_src/typo3

index.php -> typo3_src/index.php.

Your command would yield typo3_src -> typo3

First, try `ln -s typo3_src-9.5.8  typo3_src` and see if that fixes the problem. If it does not, additionally try `ln -s typo3_src/typo3 typo3`, and then `ln -s typo3_src/index.php index.php`. It might be, that you have to rename the existing directories/files before this actually works.

Answer (score 1):

**TYPO3 version 9.0.0 to TYPO3 LTS:**  Issue is already found in the core, Please check - https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87575. So, you are facing this problem.

**TYPO3 version 9.5.6 to TYPO3 LTS:** If your project setup with below symlinks then you need just to follow TYPO3 core update wizard only.

[image]

---

[image]

```
ln -s typo3_src-9.5.6/ typo3_src
ln -s typo3_src/typo3 typo3
ln -s typo3_src/index.php
```

Please let try it.

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming you want to update Typo3 from v9.5.10 to v9.5.25***

**1 -With the current version (v9.5.10)**

```
cd  /var/www/typo3
mv  typo3_src  typo3_src_9.5.10
ln  -s  typo3_src-9.5.10  typo3_src
mv  typo3  typo3.save
ln  -s  typo3_src/typo3  .
mv  index.php  index.php.save
ln  -s  typo3_src/index.php  .
```

**2 - Download the new version (v9.5.25)**

```
wget --content-disposition get.typo3.org/9.5.25
```

**3 - unzip the new version in the /var/www/typo3/ directory**

```
tar  xvfp  typo3_src-9.5.25.tar.gz
```

**4 - Move the new version of the “core” to its destination directory**

```
cd /var/www/typo3
chown  -R  apache:apache  typo3_src-9.5.25
chmod  -R  g=u,o=u-w  typo3_src-9.5.25
rm  typo3_src
ln  -s  typo3_src-9.5.25  typo3_src
```

**5 - Now the core of your typo3 is version 9.5.25**