# Directory Status - Directory / should be a directory, but is of type link

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to update TYPO3 (current version: 9.5.20) to the most recent version, but I'm currently stuck at the following error message when using the 'Update Core' functionality to update to 9.5.32:

> Automatic TYPO3 CMS core update not possible: Folder structure has errors or warnings.

I went to 'Environment' -> 'Directory Status' and saw the following error:

> Directory / should be a directory, but is of type link

How should I go about fixing this error? I saw a handful of bug reports on the TYPO3 bugtracker but no clear way to fix this issue. Perhaps there is an option to temporarily disable the directory status checks?

The intention is obviously to update to the most recent TYPO3 version, but I'm starting with 9.5.32 as a first step.

Below are the errors I get when trying to update to v9.5.32:

[image: The directory status error]

[image: The error I get when trying to update]

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: Please add more details about the exact error including the directory name. You can also insert a screenshot for clarity.

Comment: Thanks @MathiasBrodala. I've attached two images

Comment: Probably, your symlink is not valide. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57036723/5961782

Comment: Thanks @GNB for this direction. I've been trying out some things but it appears I don't even have a typo3_src folder, the person who previously set this up either removed it or did something else.


I tried wget'ing the goal version for now (typo3-9.5.31) as a start and used the commands as stated by keval pandya but I'm still running into the same issue. Copying the files worked just fine, though.

Comment: Can anyone help out with this issue? I wasn't able to find a fix yet.

Comment: One option would be that this is a deployment setup which uses symlinks to switch between releases. Please add more details about your setup incl. deployment workflow and possibly a directory listing (`ls -la <dir>`) of the relevant directories.